# how to convert this .htaccess from Apache to Nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, convert

I need to convert this .htaccess to Nginx format, please guide me if you can.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6})$ links/?to=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,9})/banner/(.*)$ links/?uid=$1&adt=2&url=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,9})/(.*)$ links/?uid=$1&adt=1&url=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
rewrite ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6})$ /links/?to=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([0-9]{1,9})/banner/(.*)$ /links/?uid=$1&adt=2&url=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([0-9]{1,9})/(.*)$ /links/?uid=$1&adt=1&url=$2 last;
```

Source: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/